# How should I edit this question to re-open?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question two days ago: [Is the duck (curve) still a duck?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/429207/93845). It received reasonable attention -- with eight upvotes, it would be the seventh-most upvoted [unanswered question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/unanswered) on the site, out of 13,000.

To me, this indicates that were the question to hang around, someone would eventually come along who knows the answer, or how to get at one.

The close reason was **"Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic"**. I sort of get this... I am looking for a data source to help recreate and update the duck curve. But it is a data source that answers a broad and important question -- not just a specific project I'm working on.

The duck curve is a fundamental and much-discussed topic in the world of bulk electric grid management and renewable electricity. I thought of posting this to [sustainability.se](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) as similar topics are often discussed there, but I hoped that an audience of electrical engineers, some of whom are working in grid operations, would be a better source for this data.

**Am I totally off track here? Is there a better way to formulate the question in order to stay on-topic?**

Comment: The people here, who work on grid operations, certainly have much more things to say about how a transformer works, than about the satistics of grid power delivery in California over the course of the day... I honestly don't see any way to make this on-topic, and I'm pretty sure you don't have more chance to get relevant answers here, than on any other site.

Comment: I ended up asking this question on opendata and actually found the answer myself, which I posted there: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/14073/20229

Answer (score 2):

Product requests are off-topic because they are quickly out of date, and Stack Exchange is supposed to be an indexed archive of answers. Your first question about the actual data is "fresh", and how to request data isn't really on-topic IMO.

Where to find this information should be explicitly on topic at (opendata.SE)[https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic]:

> Data requests ("Where can I find data about … ?") are usually welcome for any topic.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to migrate the question to open data? I assume to trigger this I would flag for moderator attention and explain.

Comment: @LShaver It might be possible to migrate, but if you wrote the post for EE.SE, chances are it's not a good fit elsewhere. I wouldn't be comfortable migrating a question to a Stack Exchange I don't use, so before posting I would have to read about their policies and look at previous questions etc. Can't you just ask it again?

Answer (score 2):

EE.SE is for answering design questions, not every question that is related to electrical design is acceptable. The question is more of a research type question, and asking for resources. These questions are off topic on the site, but can be posted in chat. However, there are not many power design engineers here, mostly circuit design.

If you do post to another site, make sure only one question exists, cross posting across sites is against guidelines.

Comment: If the question is closed here, does that count as "existing?" Or should I also delete it? I'm reluctant to given it received more upvotes than close votes.

Comment: That counts as existing, the problem is it muddles search results. If you do move it make sure you read the help section thoroughly or ask in the site's chat if its on topic. Regardless, CASIO has the information, you should probably search through their reports or ask them directly